# Getting error : java.lang.Stackoverflowerror

Tags: android, jakarta-mail, stack-overflow

First of all I tried all java.lang.Stackoverflowerror error questions but nothing change this error. Why I am getting this error?

My ListeleActivity class is;

```
 package com.mobil.eposta;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import javax.mail.Message;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ListeleActivity extends Activity
{
    static List<String> gelen;
    static ListView listView;
    static ArrayList<String> konulist;
    static ArrayList<String> kimdenlist;
    static ArrayList<String> govdelist;
    static ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
    static ArrayList<String> dosyaIsmi;
    static Message[] messageslist;
    static int messagePosition;
    static int onClickPosition;
    static boolean messageEkBulunuyormu;

    ArrayList<String> eklist;
    int clickKonum;
    static boolean ekvar;

    ListView lv;
    Button btnSave, btnClear;
    HashMap<Integer, Boolean> mCartItems = new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();

    Baglanti baglantiNesnesi = new Baglanti();
//  EkDurumu ekdurumuNesnesi = new EkDurumu();
//  GoruntuleActivity goruntuleNesnesi = new GoruntuleActivity();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listalt);

        konulist = (ArrayList<String>) baglantiNesnesi.getKonu();
        kimdenlist = (ArrayList<String>) baglantiNesnesi.getKimden();
        govdelist = (ArrayList<String>) baglantiNesnesi.getGovde();
        messageslist = baglantiNesnesi.messages;

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        LayoutInflater mLInflater = getLayoutInflater();
        final ListViewAdapter adapter = new ListViewAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                kimdenlist, konulist, mLInflater);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onItemClick( AdapterView<?> parent, View item, 
                                       int position, long id) 
              {
                    final Intent intent = new Intent(ListeleActivity.this, GoruntuleActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    onClickPosition = position;
                    Toast.makeText(ListeleActivity.this, "Bastın", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              }
            });
    }
}
```

And my GoruntuleActivity.class is;

```
public class GoruntuleActivity extends Activity
{
    ListeleActivity listeleNesnesi = new ListeleActivity();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.epostagoruntuleme);
         }
}


   05-07 17:24:32.796: E/AndroidRuntime(728): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-07 17:24:32.796: E/AndroidRuntime(728): java.lang.StackOverflowError
05-07 17:24:32.796: E/AndroidRuntime(728):  at java.lang.Thread.currentThread(Thread.java:588)
05-07 17:24:32.796: E/AndroidRuntime(728):  at java.lang.ThreadLocal.get(ThreadLocal.java:59)
05-07 17:24:32.796: E/AndroidRuntime(728):  at android.os.Looper.myLooper(Looper.java:137)
05-07 17:24:32.796: E/AndroidRuntime(728):  at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:119)
05-07 17:24:32.796: E/AndroidRuntime(728):  at android.app.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:679)
05-07 17:24:32.796: E/AndroidRuntime(728):  at com.mobil.eposta.GoruntuleActivity.<init>(GoruntuleActivity.java:23)
05-07 17:24:32.796: E/AndroidRuntime(728):  at com.mobil.eposta.ListeleActivity.<init>(ListeleActivity.java:48)
05-07 17:24:32.796: E/AndroidRuntime(728):  at com.mobil.eposta.GoruntuleActivity.<init>(GoruntuleActivity.java:25)
05-07 17:24:32.796: E/AndroidRuntime(728):  at com.mobil.eposta.ListeleActivity.<init>(ListeleActivity.java:48)
05-07 17:24:32.796: E/AndroidRuntime(728):  at com.mobil.eposta.GoruntuleActivity.<init>(GoruntuleActivity.java:25)
05-07 17:24:32.796: E/AndroidRuntime(728):  at com.mobil.eposta.ListeleActivity.<init>(ListeleActivity.java:48)
05-07 17:24:32.796: E/AndroidRuntime(728):  at com.mobil.eposta.GoruntuleActivity.<init>(GoruntuleActivity.java:25)
05-07 17:24:32.796: E/AndroidRuntime(728):  at com.mobil.eposta.ListeleActivity.<init>(ListeleActivity.java:48)
05-07 17:24:32.796: E/AndroidRuntime(728):  at com.mobil.eposta.GoruntuleActivity.<init>(GoruntuleActivity.java:25)
05-07 17:24:32.796: E/AndroidRuntime(728):  at com.mobil.eposta.ListeleActivity.<init>(ListeleActivity.java:48)
05-07 17:24:32.796: E/AndroidRuntime(728):  at com.mobil.eposta.GoruntuleActivity.<init>(GoruntuleActivity.java:25)
05-07 17:24:32.796: E/AndroidRuntime(728):  at com.mobil.eposta.ListeleActivity.<init>(ListeleActivity.java:48)
05-07 17:24:32.796: E/AndroidRuntime(728):  at com.mobil.eposta.GoruntuleActivity.<init>(GoruntuleActivity.java:25)
05-07 17:24:32.796: E/AndroidRuntime(728):  at com.mobil.eposta.ListeleActivity.<init>(ListeleActivity.java:48)
05-07 17:24:32.796: E/AndroidRuntime(728):  at com.mobil.eposta.GoruntuleActivity.<init>(GoruntuleActivity.java:25)
05-07 17:24:32.796: E/AndroidRuntime(728):  at com.mobil.eposta.ListeleActivity.<init>(ListeleActivity.java:48)
05-07 17:24:32.796: E/AndroidRuntime(728):  at com.mobil.eposta.GoruntuleActivity.<init>(GoruntuleActivity.java:25)
05-07 17:24:32.796: E/AndroidRuntime(728):  at com.mobil.eposta.ListeleActivity.<init>(ListeleActivity.java:48)
05-07 17:24:32.796: E/AndroidRuntime(728):  at com.mobil.eposta.GoruntuleActivity.<init>(GoruntuleActivity.java:25)
05-07 17:24:32.796: E/AndroidRuntime(728):  at com.mobil.eposta.ListeleActivity.<init>(ListeleActivity.java:48)
05-07 17:24:32.796: E/AndroidRuntime(728):  at com.mobil.eposta.GoruntuleActivity.<init>(GoruntuleActivity.java:25)
05-07 17:24:32.796: E/AndroidRuntime(728):  at com.mobil.eposta.ListeleActivity.<init>(ListeleActivity.java:48)
05-07 17:24:32.796: E/AndroidRuntime(728):  at com.mobil.eposta.GoruntuleActivity.<init>(GoruntuleActivity.java:25)
05-07 17:24:32.796: E/AndroidRuntime(728):  at com.mobil.eposta.ListeleActivity.<init>(ListeleActivity.java:48)
05-07 17:24:32.796: E/AndroidRuntime(728):  at com.mobil.eposta.GoruntuleActivity.<init>(GoruntuleActivity.java:25)
05-07 17:24:32.796: E/AndroidRuntime(728):  at com.mobil.eposta.ListeleActivity.<init>(ListeleActivity.java:48)
05-07 17:24:32.796: E/AndroidRuntime(728):  at com.mobil.eposta.GoruntuleActivity.<init>(GoruntuleActivity.java:25)
05-07 17:24:32.796: E/AndroidRuntime(728):  at com.mobil.eposta.ListeleActivity.<init>(ListeleActivity.java:48)
05-07 17:24:32.796: E/AndroidRuntime(728):  at com.mobil.eposta.GoruntuleActivity.<init>(GoruntuleActivity.java:25)
05-07 17:24:32.796: E/AndroidRuntime(728):  at com.mobil.eposta.ListeleActivity.<init>(ListeleActivity.java:48)
05-07 17:24:32.796: E/AndroidRuntime(728):  at com.mobil.eposta.GoruntuleActivity.<init>(GoruntuleActivity.java:25)
05-07 17:24:32.796: E/AndroidRuntime(728):  at com.mobil.eposta.ListeleActivity.<init>(ListeleActivity.java:48)
05-07 17:24:32.796: E/AndroidRuntime(728):  at com.mobil.eposta.GoruntuleActivity.<init>(GoruntuleActivity.java:25)
05-07 17:24:32.796: E/AndroidRuntime(728):  at com.mobil.eposta.ListeleActivity.<init>(ListeleActivity.java:48)
05-07 17:24:32.796: E/AndroidRuntime(728):  at com.mobil.eposta.GoruntuleActivity.<init>(GoruntuleActivity.java:25)
05-07 17:24:32.796: E/AndroidRuntime(728):  at com.mobil.eposta.ListeleActivity.<init>(ListeleActivity.java:48)
05-07 17:24:32.796: E/AndroidRuntime(728):  at com.mobil.eposta.GoruntuleActivity.<init>(GoruntuleActivity.java:25)
05-07 17:24:32.796: E/AndroidRuntime(728):  at com.mobil.eposta.ListeleActivity.<init>(ListeleActivity.java:48)
05-07 17:24:32.796: E/AndroidRuntime(728):  at com.mobil.eposta.GoruntuleActivity.<init>(GoruntuleActivity.java:25)
05-07 17:24:32.796: E/AndroidRuntime(728):  at com.mobil.eposta.ListeleActivity.<init>(ListeleActivity.java:48)
05-07 17:24:32.796: E/AndroidRuntime(728):  at com.mobil.eposta.GoruntuleActivity.<init>(GoruntuleActivity.java:25)
05-07 17:24:32.796: E/AndroidRuntime(728):  at com.mobil.eposta.ListeleActivity.<init>(ListeleActivity.java:48)
05-07 17:24:32.796: E/AndroidRuntime(728):  at com.mobil.eposta.GoruntuleActivity.<init>(GoruntuleActivity.java:25)
05-07 17:24:32.796: E/AndroidRuntime(728):  at com.mobil.eposta.ListeleActivity.<init>(ListeleActivity.java:48)
05-07 17:24:32.796: E/AndroidRuntime(728):  at com.mobil.eposta.GoruntuleActivity.<init>(GoruntuleActivity.java:25)
05-07 17:24:32.796: E/AndroidRuntime(728):  at com.mobil.eposta.ListeleActivity.<init>(ListeleActivity.java:48)
05-07 17:24:32.796: E/AndroidRuntime(728):  at com.mobil.eposta.GoruntuleActivity.<init>(GoruntuleActivity.java:25)
05-07 17:24:32.796: E/AndroidRuntime(728):  at com.mobil.eposta.ListeleActivity.<init>(ListeleActivity.java:48)
05-07 17:24:32.796: E/AndroidRuntime(728):  at com.mobil.eposta.GoruntuleActivity.<init>(GoruntuleActivity.java:25)
05-07 17:24:32.796: E/AndroidRuntime(728):  at com.mobil.eposta.ListeleActivity.<init>(ListeleActivity.java:48)
05-07 17:24:32.796: E/AndroidRuntime(728):  at com.mobil.eposta.GoruntuleActivity.<init>(GoruntuleActivity.java:25)
05-07 17:24:32.796: E/AndroidRuntime(728):  at com.mobil.eposta.ListeleActivity.<init>(ListeleActivity.java:48)
05-07 17:24:32.796: E/AndroidRuntime(728):  at com.mobil.eposta.GoruntuleActivity.<init>(GoruntuleActivity.ja
05-07 17:24:33.006: D/dalvikvm(728): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 3074 objects / 569272 bytes in 124ms
05-07 17:29:33.127: I/Process(728): Sending signal. PID: 728 SIG: 9
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mobil.eposta"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MobilEpostaUygActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
         <activity android:name=".ListeleActivity"/>
         <activity android:name=".GoruntuleActivity"/>
    </application>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
</manifest>
```

Comment: what line in your code is throwing the error? could you post the actual logcat for us?

Comment: 05-07 17:24:32.796: E/AndroidRuntime(728):  at com.mobil.eposta.GoruntuleActivity.<init>(GoruntuleActivity.java:23) shows : public class GoruntuleActivity extends Activity

Comment: Is there a constructor for ListeleActivity in your code?  Does ListeleActivity extend GoruntuleActivity?

Comment: No there is not, I will change the ListeleActivity at question and give all class for you can see all class

Comment: `ListeleActivity listeleNesnesi = new ListeleActivity();` is suspicious. Do you have a similar line in `ListeleActivity` instantiating a `GoruntuleActivity`?

Comment: I edited my all ListeleActivity class . There is GoruntuleActivity object but it is not using now

Comment: Please post the entire error list, all the way to "... xx more".

Comment: I edit all logcat error block

Comment: Line 48 shows: public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  in ListeleActivity and Line 25 shows:  ListeleActivity listeleNesnesi = new ListeleActivity(); in GoruntuleActivity

Comment: Are those classes subclasses of one another?

Comment: I dont think so, Could you please say how can they are subclass the other ones? Please.. I add my Manifestfile into my question too

Comment: I still suspect the code you are running has that line instantiating `GoruntuleActivity` active. That would cause the `<init>` methods to ping pong like that. In fact, you shouldn't ever need to instantiate an activity yourself, so you might as well get rid of the `new ListeleActivity()` line.

Comment: @vhallac - you've identified the problem, can you present this an answer with a good explanation

Comment: Thank you so much @vhallac!!!!!!!!!!! You rescue me very big problem!! Thank you again

Comment: No they can't be subclasses of one another. I either overlooked the first part of the first listing or there was an edit. Sorry,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't create activities yourself. These lines are unnecessary (and cause your stack overflow):

```
ListeleActivity listeleNesnesi = new ListeleActivity();

GoruntuleActivity goruntuleNesnesi = new GoruntuleActivity();
```

Instead of calling the activities' constructors, you create them by creating a new `Intent` and passing it to [`startActivity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivity%28android.content.Intent%29). Read this doc on [Android Fundamentals](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html) for more explanation.